# AWS Kinesis Analytics aggregate tumbling time windows results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

In AWS Kinesis Analytics, how to aggregate the results between tumbling time windows ?

Let's say there are 10 seconds tumbling time windows, like in the given example from AWS website:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM" 
(ticker_symbol VARCHAR(4), ticker_symbol_count INTEGER);

CREATE OR REPLACE  PUMP "STREAM_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"
SELECT STREAM ticker_symbol, COUNT(*) AS ticker_symbol_count
FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001"
GROUP BY ticker_symbol, 
  FLOOR(("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00') SECOND / 10 TO SECOND);
```

Every 10 seconds a new tumbling window is generated with different results. The second window doesn't keep track of the previous window results. Is there any way we can combine all tumbling windows results?

Basically to have something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM" 
(ticker_symbol VARCHAR(4), ticker_symbol_count INTEGER);

CREATE OR REPLACE  PUMP "STREAM_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"
SELECT STREAM ticker_symbol, COUNT(*) AS ticker_symbol_count
FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001"
--> UNION WITH RESULTS FROM THE PREVIOUS WINDOW
GROUP BY ticker_symbol, 
  FLOOR(("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00') SECOND / 10 TO SECOND);
```